# Replace HTC Sense "recent apps" by stock ICS

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, htc-sense, recents-screen

I've just ordered my new HTC One X phone which will be my first Android phone and ships with Android ICS and HTC Sense. I've seen some reviews on YouTube and the only thing I didn't like from HTC Sense was the "style" they use in the "recent apps"-switcher. Is there any way to revert only that one "style" back to original ICS? Maybe someone could also explain to me what the "Launchers" are everyone is talking about... Are they like the explorer.exe on Windows? Are they responsible for the whole look and feel? Or is something like the "recent apps"-switcher a separate process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question about launchers:

Yes, they are like explorer.exe on Windows. Most launchers will replace the home screens and app-launching window. Some may even affect the app-switching, but you might have to play around with them.

A short list (note: not complete) of Alternative Launcher apps:

- [Nova Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher&feature=nav_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDMsImNvbS50ZXNsYWNvaWxzdy5sYXVuY2hlciJd)
- [ADWLauncher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.adw.launcher&feature=more_from_developer#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwMiwib3JnLmFkdy5sYXVuY2hlciJd) / [ADWLauncher EX](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.adwfreak.launcher&feature=more_from_developer#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwMiwib3JnLmFkd2ZyZWFrLmxhdW5jaGVyIl0.) (Paid)
- [Go Launcher EX](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gau.go.launcherex&feature=related_apps#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwOSwiY29tLmdhdS5nby5sYXVuY2hlcmV4Il0.)
- [LauncherPro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fede.launcher&feature=search_result) / [LauncherPro Plus Unlocker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fede.launcherproplusunlocker&feature=more_from_developer#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwMiwiY29tLmZlZGUubGF1bmNoZXJwcm9wbHVzdW5sb2NrZXIiXQ..) (Paid)

Looking at the above apps you can see how they change the look-and-feel of the bulk of Android's UI.

I have tried most of the above, and each have extensive options and tweaking abilities to get your home screens and app launchers to look the way you want them.